# Strip off previous lines in tail or less

Tags: linux, logging, console, tail

I'm using `tail -f` or `less +F` to observe a changing log-file. I know from a certain point the lines I'm looking for are going to appear.

So all that garbage before that point I don't require and would like to strip it off somehow.

Is there a way to accomplish that? Mustn't be `tail` or `less`, I'm not limited to that.

Comment: Suppose the input were `seq 100`, and it was known that only lines greater than *50* had the needed lines.  Let's say the needed lines are  *61* and *63*... is the goal to print from *61* to *100* (40 lines) or just *61* and *63*, (2 lines)?

Comment: I wish it was so clear. I see the program and the logs parallel and as a certain point in the program is reached I know the line I expect will appear in the next 3-5 seconds. Everything written in the log before that point is not relevant and I'd like to strip it off.

Answer (score 0):

Use `tail -F <logfile> | grep '<string>'` and you'll only see lines containing `<string>`.

Comment: I don't know which string I'm waiting for. I just know the timeframe it will be read into the logfile.

Comment: So, you have something like from this time to that time like, 09:45:00 to 10:20:59, for example? `awk` could help in such a case, unless you want to write some parsing program using `python`, `perl`, `bash`, or any other scripting language. Or you could use`sed`'s *range* feature, as in `tail -F /var/log/syslog | sed -n -e '/ 09:45:/,/ 10:15:/p'`, to print all log entries from 09:45 to 10:15.

Comment: There is a time in the beginning, but sometimes there are 50+ logs per second coming in (not always, but sometimes). It can be I have to split 11:31:33 in a half, and throw away everything before and everything past the first quarter of 11:31:36 is not so interesting too

Comment: Ok, there *has* to be something you're looking for. `sed`, `awk`, `grep` and piping can get you far enough, plus you can limit what you're searching for with `regex`es of the form `/09:45:.*source_of_message.*begin_of_interesting_message/,/10:15.*end/`

Comment: So far I mostly know what the entry doesn't look like. Mostly things like `Client: gotNewMsg type M_TRANSACTION` and other ones as they appear all over. So far I'm mostly looking for messages different to them and refer to specific objects (but I don't know how they are named, it's partly guessing too I fear)

Comment: In that case, why don't you start *excluding* lines? Finish off your command line with something like `..... | grep -v 'not_this\|nor_this\|neither_this'`, i.e `... | grep -v 'Client: gotNewMsg type M_TRANSACTION'`